# Azure AD B2C Authentication Firewall Issues

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have implemented a website that uses Azure AD B2C as its authentication mechanism.

Everything works great except I recently ran into a firewall issue with one of my clients.  When the client redirects to either `*.onmicrosoft.com` and/or `login.microsoftonline.com` my client's corporate firewall blocks the routes.  And to further complicate my situation my client's corporate firewall restrictions can not be changed.

Is there any work around that anyone can suggest such using a headless login workflow that is orchestrated within the web server that hosts my website or possibly using custom domains that my client trusts such as login.mycompany.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both of the approaches have outlined would be the ideal ways to deal with this restriction, unfortunately neither are currently available in Azure AD B2C.**

Both of them are listed in the Azure AD B2C feedback forum for you to support and keep track of their progress:

- [Customer-owned domains](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334317-customer-owned-domains)
- [Add support for Resource Owner Password Credentials flow in Azure AD B2C and headless authentication in Microsoft Authentication Library](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential)

I can't think of any other approach, which is a good thing otherwise, it would mean someone could easily spoof Azure AD B2C.

**Ultimately, the right thing to do is to work with your client to ensure these and all the endpoints your applications needs, are allowed through the firewall.**

Comment: Microsoft released *.b2clogin.com: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin#benefits-of-b2clogincom Not sure if this is the solution they mean in the "Customer-owned domains" link you attached.

Answer (score 0):

Saca is correct, the customer owned domains feature could be used to change the domain name when it becomes available.  Work has started, but it's still going to be some time before it's publicly available.

Regarding your client's firewall restriction that blocks login.microsoftonline.com.  If it helps, there are some things that your client should be aware of.  Blocking this domain doesn't just prevent application / Azure AD B2C scenarios, it blocks all Azure Active Directory sign-ins used for Microsoft Office 365 and Microsoft Azure.  This means that if some other organization were to share Microsoft resources with one of the employees of your client's organization, they would be unable to access them.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back.  I will keep track of both of the mentioned work items.  But for now I will have to decouple my application from B2C.  I figured that login.microsoftonline.com would block several resources available via Microsoft.  But in the financial services sector its just the nature of the sector to over secure and provide stringent rails.  Some companies are more lax than others e.g. large investment banks normally have strict firewall policies and to change those policies it may take months and committee approval.  They also maybe blocking redirect dance between domains.